# Exotic case of Galaxy Nexus not booting

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, adb, battery, boot, touchscreen

Symptoms :

1. Put battery into Galaxy Nexus (tried with two different including a brand new one)
2. Plug cord to USB host or charger
3. Large battery charge indicator icon appears in the middle of the screen
4. Six seconds later the screen goes dark and no further user-observable activity happens
5. During the whole process, device does not react to any button input - including the 'while holding down Volume Up and Volume Down buttons together, hold down the Power button for ten seconds' maneuver that should have taken it to fastboot mode
6. When plugged to an USB host, no USB activity is detected from the host - whether by adb or other USB observation tools.

Context :

- The device having suffered a cracked screen, it has been swapped for a new screen
- This problem appeared on first boot attempt after the screen swap
- The device worked perfectly before suffering the cracked screen
- The appearance of the battery icon proves that the replacement screen works

I may have broken something during swapping the screens... But with disabled hardware I would have expected a frankly non-functional device.

What further steps can I take to find what makes the boot process fail in the aforementioned way ?